# wrapping Wordpress content in paragraph tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to remove the `<blockquotes>` from my Wordpress posts and put just the content/images.

I want the content to be wrapped in `<p>` tags at each line break (so I can hav different paragraphs

I have the following html

```
    <?php
        $block2 = get_the_content();
        $block2 = preg_replace('~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~', '', $block2);
        echo $block2;
    ?>
```

I can't get the paragraphs in `<p>` tags though

Comment: I'm a little confused. So you're trying to remove blockquotes and replace them with nothing (empty string). And then you're trying to wrap all of that content in paragraph tags? Is that correct?

Comment: exactly, I want to post the content as it normally would (with paragraph tags around each paragraph) just with the blockquotes completely removed (and their space they would have taken removed) They are used elsewhere in my site

Answer (score 0):

You just replace tag otherwise past content normally.
WordPress Provide some default content formatting. like add P tag automatically.

Comment: I want to remove the blockqoutes which always seems to strip all the formatting